# Python. Code leaves blank rows in csv file after every row

Tags: python, csv

Why code deletes not only winningRows, but also csv header row and leaves blank row after every row? How to fix it? I only need to delete winningRows, no blank rows needed.

```
def generate():
    global winningRows
    filename = enterFile()

    noOfWinners = 5
    winningNumbers = []
    while len(winningNumbers) < noOfWinners:
        luckyNumber = random.randint(1, totalEntries)
        if luckyNumber not in winningNumbers:
            winningNumbers.append(luckyNumber)

    with open(filename, newline="") as entriesCSV:
        entriesDict = csv.DictReader(entriesCSV,dialect="excel")
        allRows = [row for row in entriesDict]
        winningRows = [row for row in allRows if int(row["#"]) in winningNumbers]
        nonWinningRows = [row for row in allRows if int(row["#"]) not in winningNumbers]
        for row in winningRows:
            winnerName = row["Name"]
            winnerID = row["ID"]
            winnerEmail = row["Email"]
            print(f"The winner is {winnerName}, ID {winnerID}, email {winnerEmail}")

        csv.DictWriter(open(filename, "w"), fieldnames=["#", "Name", "ID", "Email"]).writeheader()
        csv.DictWriter(open(filename, "w"), fieldnames=["#", "Name", "ID", "Email"]).writerows(nonWinningRows)
```

[csv before running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPhwP.png)

[csv after running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUb9I.png)

It seems this is working:

```
with open(filename, newline='\n') as entriesCSV:
    entriesDict = csv.DictReader(entriesCSV,dialect="excel")
    allRows = [row for row in entriesDict]
    winningRows = [row for row in allRows if int(row["#"]) in winningNumbers]
    nonWinningRows = [row for row in allRows if int(row["#"]) not in winningNumbers]
    for row in winningRows:
        winnerName = row["Name"]
        winnerID = row["ID"]
        winnerEmail = row["Email"]
        print(f"The winner is {winnerName}, ID {winnerID}, email {winnerEmail}")

with open(filename, "w", newline='\n') as entriesCSV:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(entriesCSV, fieldnames=["#", "Name", "ID", "Email"])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(nonWinningRows)
```

But in this case, I am opening the file twice, right?

Comment: Can you print out `nonWinningRows` and verify that the array doesn't have any blanks in it

Comment: Maybe there is a trailing line seperator in email. Try `winnerEmail = row["Email"]`  to `winnerEmail = row["Email"].strip()`. As mentioned by @MB - Please add more details for help. If your problem is solved - please comment

Comment: @MB, no array doesn't have any blanks.

Comment: @sam, .strip() doesn't worked.

Comment: Sorry to hear! Can you also try  please change `open(filename, newline="")` to `open(filename, newline="\n")` ? You are having `\n` in you rows, you need to identify.

Comment: You need to open the file twice, once for reading and once for writing. It's just important that you don't do it at the same time, otherwise you can get errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are on Windows.  Add the `newline` argument to your `open` function.

```
with open(filename, "w", newline='\n') as fp:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fp, fieldnames=["#", "Name", "ID", "Email"])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(nonWinningRows)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are opening the same file multiple times in parallel. I can't test this without the data, but does this work?

```
with open(filename, newline="") as entriesCSV:
    entriesDict = csv.DictReader(entriesCSV,dialect="excel")

allRows = [row for row in entriesDict]
winningRows = [row for row in allRows if int(row["#"]) in winningNumbers]
nonWinningRows = [row for row in allRows if int(row["#"]) not in winningNumbers]
for row in winningRows:
    winnerName = row["Name"]
    winnerID = row["ID"]
    winnerEmail = row["Email"]
    print(f"The winner is {winnerName}, ID {winnerID}, email {winnerEmail}")

with open(filename, "w") as outputCSV:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outputCSV, fieldnames=["#", "Name", "ID", "Email"])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(nonWinningRows)
```

Comment: no, it's not... but this, at least, don't delete header row.

Comment: It sounds like some fields have whitespace. Does this work? `allRows = [[x.strip() for x in row] for row in entriesDict]`

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: yes, your code was actually right. I just changed newline="" into newline='\n' when reading and added the same when writing to file. Thanks!